# Encoding in javascript application

Tags: react-native, encoding, utf-8, xmlhttprequest, iconv

I am implementing mobile app in React Native that needs to work with charset of certain language (Czech). At first, I call this page in **xmlhttprequest** to download all plain text data that are encoded with **WINDOWS-1250** encoding (http://www.cbdx.cz/denikcl6/add/denikcl6.tom). As I realised xmlhttrequest as default converts this text to **UTF-8** . Now I tried to convert back this UTF-8 converted text back to WINDOWS-1250 with iconv-lite but it looks like it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    var type = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    if (type.indexOf("text") !== 1) {
      setDownText(
        iconv
          .decode(Buffer.from(request.response), "windows-1250")
          .substring(0, 100)
      );
      console.log(downText);
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal to have same exact text as is this? Here is my expected output vs real one. [image: desired output]

[image: actual output]

Comment: This will never work, because the HTTP response comes with no hint at its text encoding, just `Content-Type: text/plain`. And I doubt the conversion **to** UTF-8 is done **from** CP1250. Even worse CP1250 must be considered unknown to internet use, and only known to desktops.

Comment: @AmigoJack So there isn't any way to achieve this? If I will be able to encode this special czech chars in some ISO coding it is still problem right because fetch will treat them as UTF-8.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this with JavaScript. When writing your own HTTP client you could deal with the raw bytes and your own knowledge that the sent text is CP1250 encoded. Or explain the server owners why a non UTF-8 text resource has more disadvantages.

Comment: Please, did you solve it, I need to send CP1250 to a server, this might help me a lot

Comment: No unfortunately with React Native I wasn't able to decode data in desired encoding. I don't know if CP1250 is same as WINDOWS1250 though.